# Logstash - HTTP plugin, Certificate Authority validation not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I am trying to get HTTP requests to write logs into Elastic Search.

We are using Logstash for that with the HTTP plugin. Here is my configuration:

```
input { 
    http {  
        port => 8000
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate => "/private/ssl/__example_com.crt"
        ssl_key => "/private/ssl/example_com.key"
        ssl_certificate_authorities => ["/private/ssl/__example_com.ca-bundle"]
        ssl_verify_mode => "peer"
    }
}
output {
    sdtout {}
}
```

When I use Postman I get a response only if I **DISABLE** "SSL certificate verification"